# Rigorous proof that cardinality of a disjoint union is the sum of cardinalities for finite sets

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, peano-axioms

In a lot of books there are intuitive(but sort of hand wavy) proofs for finite, disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ that
$$
  |A \cup B| = |A| + |B|
$$
since $A = \{a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots,a_{|A|}\}$ and $B = \{b_1,b_2,b_3,\cdots,b_{|B|}\}$ are disjoint collections, and we can list them as
$$
  a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots,a_{|A|},b_{|A| + 1},b_{|A| + 2},b_{|A| + 3},\cdots,b_{|A| + |B|}.
$$
For a more rigorous proof, would we first prove
$$
  f: k \longmapsto m + k, \quad 1 \leq k \leq n
$$
is a bijection to $\{m + 1,m + 2,m+3,\cdots,m+n\}$, and then show $1,2,3,\cdots,|A|$ and $|A| + 1, |A| + 2, |A| + 3,\cdots, |A| + |B|$ exhausts all naturals $1 \leq k \leq |A| + |B|$. I was somewhat amazed at how complicated [Proof Wiki's version](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Principle_of_Counting) went and was wondering if we really needed all the machinery that they used.

Comment: The definition of $|A|+|B|$ is that you take disjoint copies of $A$ and $B$ and you take the cardinality of their union; that is, $|A|+|B| = |(A\times\{0\})\cup(B\times\{1\})|$. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then there is a clear bijection between $(A\times\{0\})\cup (B\times\{1\})$ and $A\cup B$ (regardless of whether they were finite ro not).

Comment: The proof wiki that you point to is not a proof about the cardinality of a disjoint union of two sets, it is a proof that the sum of the sizes of all elements of an arbitrary partition of a finite set equals the size of the finite set. Those are related, but different, statements.

Comment: Any very rigorous proof would exhibit a bijection between $A \sqcup B$ and $\{ 1 , \dots, |A| + |B|\}$ by constructing an explicit bijection between $\{ 1 , \dots , |A| + |B| \} $ and $ \{ 1 , \dots , |A| \} \sqcup \{ 1 , \dots, |B|\}$ But this is overkill

Comment: Well, the proof wiki was for any partition into any number of sets and yours is for just two sets.  Of course we could just use induction.  Hmmm.... I wonder it'd be harder or easier to prove if $A\subset B$ both finite prove $|B\setminus A| = |B| -|A|$.

Comment: Why isn't it enough to show that there's a bijection between $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $\{m+1,\dots,m+n\}$? Then, if $|A|=m$ and $|B|=n$, there are bijections $A\to\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $B\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ (by definition), so there's a bijection $B\to\{m+1,\dots,m+n\}$; the union of the bijections $A\to\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $B\to\{m+1,\dots,m+n\}$ is a bijection $A\cup B\to\{1,\dots,m+n\}$. Is that too hand-wavy?